# forkJoin is not working. But no errors too

Tags: angular, rxjs, ionic3, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

**Update:**

Very strange. I have to use `.valueChanges().pipe(first())`. Then it is working fine. Any clue for this behavior? Is that `firestore` issue or `angularfire2`? If I'll use that pattern then I'll miss the real-time database feature here. So what should I do here?

**Old**

It seems I have done something wrong here.Could you tell me where is the issue? It doesn't give any errors. But it is not working too.

*Note:* `this.budgetGroups$` doesn't have any values. But `this.defaultBudgetGroups$` has value. Any clue?

*select-budget-group.ts*

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs/observable/forkJoin';
import { concat } from 'lodash';

budgetGroups$: Observable<BudgetGroup[]>; defaultBudgetGroups$: Observable<BudgetGroup[]>

 constructor(){}

 ionViewDidEnter() {
   this.getAllBudgetGroups();
 }

 getAllBudgetGroups() {
  this.budgetGroups$ = this.budgetGroupProvider.getAllTempBudgetGroups().valueChanges();
  this.defaultBudgetGroups$ = this.budgetGroupProvider.getDefaultBudgetGroups().valueChanges();

  forkJoin([this.budgetGroups$, this.defaultBudgetGroups$]).subscribe(res => {
      this.budgetGroupSortedList = concat(res[0], res[1]);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
   });
  }
```

*provider.ts*

```
  getDefaultBudgetGroups(): AngularFirestoreCollection<BudgetGroup> {
    return this.fireStore.collection(`defaultBudgetGroups`);
  }

 getAllTempBudgetGroups(): AngularFirestoreCollection<BudgetGroup> {
    return this.fireStore.collection(`members/${this.authenticationProvider.member.id}/budgetGroups`);
  }
```

Comment: Maybe silly, but is getAllBudgetGroups() being called inyour OnInit() hook? Also are you saying when ForkJoin emits, budgetGroup doesn't have a value? What about ForkJoin isn't working?

Comment: Actually, `this.budgetGroups$` doesn't have value. But `this.defaultBudgetGroups$` has value in my use case. `What about ForkJoin isn't working`? It should return all the values of `this.defaultBudgetGroups$`. But it doesn't return anything. Any clue? Please see the update on my post too. @joshrathke

Comment: I'm still a little unclear. Is `this.budgetGroup$` emitting even an empty array? ForkJoin wont' return anything until all Observables have emitted at least one value.

Comment: Oh.. Then which operator should I use here? This `this.budgetGroup$` can be `null` or `undefine` or whatever at times. So whcih operator is suitable here? @joshrathke

Comment: Is that data dependent on one another? If not you could just break them out into different Subscriptions. Is there no way to get your `this.budgetGroup$` to at least emit an empty array or something? I'm not familiar with Firebase??? so I don't know, but it seems like you would want your API to at least return something, even it didn't find any data. That would be the ideal solution, espeically in an RxJs environment.

Comment: There is no dependent on each other. Those are completely 2 different observables. When I use individual `subscription` then it works. This `this.budgetGroup$` returns `length = 0` `array(0)` response. I would like to do both operations at once since I need to stop the loader icon. Any clue? @joshrathke

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
forkJoin(this.budgetGroups$, this.defaultBudgetGroups$).subscribe(res => {
    this.budgetGroupSortedList = concat(res[0], res[1]);
  }, err => {
     console.log(err);
 });
}
```

** notice the removal of the destructuring array notation for the forkJoin parameter.

Alternatively, you could do:

```
forkJoin([this.budgetGroups$, this.defaultBudgetGroups$]).subscribe((result1, result2) => {
    this.budgetGroupSortedList = concat(result1, result2);
  }, err => {
     console.log(err);
 });
}
```

** notice that the parameters passed to the subscribe handler is no longer an array

Basically, the usage of forkJoin is:

```
forkJoin(array).subscribe((p1,p2,p3,etc)=> {...})
```

And

```
forkJoin(p1,p2,p3,etc).subscribe((array)=> {...})
```

Comment: I have tried 1st one. It is not working still. The 2nd method has a compile-time error. `Argument of type '(result1: any, result2: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: BudgetGroup[][]) => void'.`. Any clue why this is?

Comment: For the second method, did you add back the array notation around the forkjoin parameter?

Comment: Yes, I have copied your one above. But no luck yet?

Comment: sorry, not sure what else might be wrong...

Comment: Individual `subscribe` are working fine. But not with `forkjoin`. Any clue?

Comment: Very strange. I have to use `.valueChanges().pipe(first()`. Then it is working fine. Any clue for this behavior? Is that `firestore` issue or?

Comment: If I'll use that pattern then I'll miss the real-time database feature here no?

Comment: @Sampath _Individual subscribe are working fine._ does that mean both observables return value? or one of them doesnt?

Comment: Please see this comment. @SurajRao https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48799543/forkjoin-is-not-working-but-no-errors-too/48799891?noredirect=1#comment84602359_48799543

Comment: @Sampath https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2188#issuecomment-266521238

Comment: Hmm... What is the solution for me then?  @SurajRao Did you see my **Update** too?

Comment: what if you add a switchMap where you return `Observable.of({})` if data is null or empty to the first Observable? Or convert to promises and use Promise.all...

Comment: I think a quirk with forkJoin not about Firestore

Comment: It would be great if you can construct an answer? @SurajRao

Comment: @Sampath switchMap worked?

Comment: Please put that and after that, I'll test it :) @SurajRao

Comment: actually... dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931476/forkjoin-returns-no-results ?

Comment: that is a better way and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931476/forkjoin-returns-no-results#comment76850748_44932982 tellls you the issue

Comment: Excellent I'll try that and will let you know. Thanks a lot :) @SurajRao